# LTL representation for the following statements: both eventually vs eventually both

Tags: logic

Q and R are both eventually false:

I understood this to mean that both Q and R need not be false in the same state in the future i.e. they can be false in different states.

So, my answer is $\diamond \neg Q \land \diamond \neg R$

Q and R are eventually both false:
I understood this to mean that both Q and R are together false in the same state in the future.

So,my answer is $\diamond$($\neg$Q $\land$ $\neg$R)

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It is possible...

Comment: $\diamond \phi$ reads: ["$\phi$  *eventually* has to hold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) i.e. it will hold in (some) future. Thus in "are both eventually false" the temporal modality  is predicated [de re](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_dicto_and_de_re#Representing_de_dicto_and_de_re_in_modal_logic) while in "are eventually both false" it is predicated *de dicto*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you elaborate on de re and de dicto? I don't understand how "about the thing" and how "about what is said" fits in this context.

Comment: It is only an analogy; see the post [de-dicto-de-re-distinction-and-propositional-modal-logic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192810/de-dicto-de-re-distinction-and-propositional-modal-logic): de dicto (in sensu composito) when (the modality) is applied to the complete statement; de re (in sensu diviso) when applied to the components.